# Mysql - replace all col values by function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to modify all values in a column with a function. 
I have wrote a function and added it to stored function. 
I have wrote a stored procedure that will loop over all the values in the column with a cursor and switch the values.

This is a windows server running wamp, php 5.6, mysql 5.0
Tried ec2 linux server with mysql 5.6 as well.

```
    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_proc` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `my_proc`() 
    BEGIN

    DECLARE val1 INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE val2 INT DEFAULT NULL;


    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE cursor1  CURSOR FOR SELECT `col1` FROM  `table1` WHERE 1; 


    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cursor1;

    my_loop: 
    LOOP

      FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO val1;

      IF done = TRUE THEN 
        LEAVE my_loop; 
      ELSE   
        SET val2 = CALL the_other_procedure1(val1);
        UPDATE  `table1`
            SET `col1` = val2
            WHERE `col1` = val1 ;

      END IF;
    END LOOP my_loop;
    END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

I get 2 errors when running it in sql section of phpmyadmin: 
            1 errors were found during analysis.

```
        Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 364)
```

and:

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL the_other_procedure1(val1);
        UPDATE  `table1`
            SET `col1` = val2
            WHER' at line 25
```

[Here](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/perform-row-operations-using-mysql-cursors.html) is an example on update in the same table we read from.

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure or a function, the calculation of the new value of `val2` is very complex?. `the_other_procedure1` is a stored procedure or function?.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

1. The statement `FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO val1;` should become just `FETCH cursor1 INTO val1;`;

and

2. The assignment `SET val2 = CALL the_other_procedure1(val1);` should be called *without* keyword `CALL`, i.e `SET val2 = the_other_procedure1(val1);`.
   Also make sure you `the_other_procedure1()` is a function (i.e. it must return some value).

Read more about [differences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) between stored procedures and functions.